# For loop confusion in C

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, integer

This is a question from a practice test that I do not fully understand.

For the code fragment

```
int i = 0, j = 0, k = 0;
for (i=-1; i<=10; ++i){ 
    j = i; ++k; 
}
```

I am asked to find the values of the variables after executing the code.

The answers are:

```
 i = 11 j = 10 k = 12
```

I don't understand how, can someone please help?

Comment: I think you meant to type: `for (i=-1; i <= 10; ++i) { j = i; ++k; }`

Comment: Yea, just fixed that, thanks

Comment: Explain what it is you don't understand, what you think the results should be, and how you went about determining that.

Comment: This question is to test your understanding of when i is incremented, and when its value is tested. Forget j and k.

Comment: I thought i would be 10 because that is the highest value i reaches in the loop, j would be 10 because j = i, and k would be eleven because k starts at 0 and is incremented with every iteration of the code (the code incremented 11 times to count from -1 to 10).  Of course, according to the solutions provided with the test these are all incorrect.  What I wish to know is how the actual solution to such a problem would be found.

Comment: I concur with Joshua. Forget i except to determine how many times the loop body executes (12). Forget j *entirely*. k is incremented once per loop iteration, and there is your answer.

Comment: "i would be 10 because that is the highest value i reaches in the loop" -- If there were true, then how could the loop condition "i<=10" ever be false?

Answer (score 5):

Understanding the value of `i` after the loop is very simple, much simpler than the sorts of other answers here. The loop condition is `i<=10` ... in order for the loop to terminate, that condition must be **false**. Clearly, the value of `i` that makes that false is 11.

The value of `j` at the end of the loop is the previous value of `i`, which is 10, and the value of `k` is the number of times the loop executed, which is 1 (for -1) + 1 (for 0) + 10 (for 1 thru 10) = 12.

Comment: Hmmm... I didn't read your answer completely before I wrote my answer.  +1 for good reasoning skills.

Answer (score 3):

i must be <= 10, so it is 11 to exit the loop and inside the last iteration of the loop, i = 10 = j.  k is 1 after the first iteration, while i is -1.  Running through the loop, you'll see:

```
k = 1, i = -1
k = 2, i = 0
k = 3, i = 1
k = 4, i = 2
k = 5, i = 3
k = 6, i = 4
k = 7, i = 5
k = 8, i = 6
k = 9, i = 7
k = 10, i = 8
k = 11, i = 9
k = 12, i = 10
```

Therefore k = 12

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps:

1. When the loop begins, all three variables are zero.
2. The loop initializer sets `i` to minus 1.
3. Loop test: `i <= 10` is true, so loop is entered.
4. Inside the loop, `j` is set to `i`, so `j` is also minus 1.
5. `k` is incremented, so `k` becomes 1.
6. the iteration ends; `i` is incremented because of the `++i`, so `i` becomes 0.
7. Loop test: since `i` is zero, `i <= 10` is true, so the loop is entered again.

In this way, the loop continues, changing `j`, `k`, and `i` in that order. So when `i` becomes 10, `j` will be 9 and `k` 11. At that point:

1. The loop is entered for the last time.
2. `j` becomes 10 as well; `k` becomes 12
3. Then `i` gets incremented to 11. The loop condition `i <= 10` is false, and the loop terminates.

So `i` is 11. `j` is 10, `k` is 12 when the loop terminates.

The key point is, after the first pass, every time the loop is entered, `j` is one less than `i`, and `k` is one greater than `i`. When the loop terminates, this is still the case.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (i=-1; i<=10; ++i){ 
    j = i; ++k; 
}
```

Here is the loop :

```
i = i +1;     <-------+
   |                  |
check condition!------|--+
   |                  |  |
j = i;                |  |
   |                  |  | 
  k++;----------------+  |
   |                     |
   +<--------------------+
   |
other code
```

at last loop

```
  i = 10
   condition == true
   j = 10;
   k = 12;
```

Then

`i= i+1`  means `i = 11` but the condition show false! loop end.

Comment: @kikuchiyo I learned this from this website , some man can draw very really cool picture!

Comment: Nice diagram, but unfortunately it is not correct. `i` is incremented at the *end* of the loop.

Comment: @andy256 Yes , I know `i` is incremented at the end of loop. so and the diagram shows so.

Answer (score 2):

Take three variables separate.
You can see the variable k would be incremented , the number of times the loop is executed.
The no. of time sit would be executed from -1 to 10 it would have done 12 iterations

```
k = 1,  i = -1,  j=-1
k = 2,  i = 0,   j=0
k = 3,  i = 1,   j=1
k = 4,  i = 2,   j=2
k = 5,  i = 3,   j=3
k = 6,  i = 4,   j=4
k = 7,  i = 5,   j=5
k = 8,  i = 6,   j=6
k = 9,  i = 7,   j=7
k = 10, i = 8,   j=8
k = 11, i = 9,   j=9
k = 12, i = 10,  j=10
```

After This i has reached its limit, but it will first increment and then check,
hence i=11, k=12 and j to a one less than the value of i i.e j= 10